# Is it reasonable to scale only the outcome variable when using linear mixed models?

Tags: mixed-model, lme4-nlme

I am exploring the relationship between a 5-class ordinal severity score modelled as numeric (predictor) and a range of continuous outcome variables. There are up to two observations per patient so I am using linear mixed models with `lme4`. Some of the continuous metrics are on very different scales and their units are not easy to interpret, so I would like to standardise them.

If I scale both the predictor and outcome variable, I understand that the β coefficient would be interpreted as "one SD increase in the severity score would result in β SDs increase in the outcome metric". To me, a one SD increase in a 5-class severity score is not very interpretable. I am considering scaling only the continuous metrics so that the interpretation will be "one unit increase in the severity score would result in β SDs increase in the outcome metric"

The models would look something like this:

```
scale(continuous_metric1) ~ severity_score + covariates + (1+patient_id) 
scale(continuous_metric2) ~ severity_score + covariates + (1+patient_id)
```

Is this a reasonable approach and is my interpretation correct? Is the β still a standardised coefficient in this case or is it called something different?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree with you, that it does not make a great deal of sense to think about standardising an ordinal variable. I have seen this done in cases with several ordinal variables with different scales, but that doesn't appear to be the situation presented here.

In the case where you only standardise the outcome and leave the ordinal explanatory variable alone, the interpretation would be as you say:

> "one unit increase in the severity score would result in $\beta$ SDs increase in the outcome metric"

... (leaving other explanatory variables unchanged).

As for what to call such a coefficient, I think you could call it "semi-" or "partially" standardised" though I don't think such terms are used universally. As always be sure to describe what you have done, why you did, and define any terms that you use, such as these, carefully.